# Which HTML tag can be used to accept dynamic class name in Orbeon Forms

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I use Orbeon Forms and I want to set a dynamic class name on a `div` or `span` (or any non-XForms tags like `xforms:output`) so that group of controls can be set with that CSS class.

```
<div class="color-with-{if(/fetch/data1='Yes') then 'green' else 'red'}">
```

But this is not working. When I look at the HTML source code after the form is rendered it seems it did not processed that dynamic part.

```
<div class="color-with-{if(/fetch/data1='Yes') then 'green' else 'red'}"
    id="xf-279">
```

However this dynamic assignment works pretty good with Orbeon tags.

```
<xforms:output value="if ((xxforms:valid(instance('account-opening-setup'),true())) 
        and (xxforms:valid(instance('form-variables'),true())))
        then 'Complete' else 'Incomplete'" 
    class="validation-{if ((xxforms:valid(instance('account-opening-setup'),true())) 
        and (xxforms:valid(instance('form-variables'),true()))) then 'complete' 
        else 'incomplete'}" />
```

Please advise which HTML tag I can use to dynamically assign a class name so that group of controls follow that class CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those expression that use the `{...XPath...}` syntax are called [attribute value templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#attribute-value-templates) (AVT), and Orbeon Forms support them in a number of XForms attributes and HTML attributes, including `class` and `style`. So your code above should be working.

It might be the case that the AVT is not interpreted because your `div` isn't in the XHTML namespace. My recommendation is to always use a prefix on your elements. Define the `xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` on the root element, and then use `xhtml:div` instead of `div`. If you find this too inconvenient, make sure you have the XHTML namespace as your default namespace declared on the root element, with `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`.

Comment: Yeah thats true. It is working when i add xhtml namespace. Excellent answer. Thanks very much.